# Create new date ranges from overlapping date ranges and assign an ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, date-range

I have the following table

```
ID  | START_DATE | END_DATE   | FEATURE
---------------------------------------
001 | 1995-08-01 | 1997-12-31 | 1
001 | 1998-01-01 | 2017-03-31 | 4
001 | 2000-06-14 | 2017-03-31 | 5
001 | 2013-04-01 | 2017-03-31 | 8
002 | 1929-10-01 | 2006-05-25 | 1
002 | 2006-05-26 | 2016-11-10 | 4
002 | 2006-05-26 | 2016-11-10 | 7
002 | 2013-04-01 | 2016-11-10 | 8
```

I want to convert this table into a consolidated table which will look for overlapping date ranges and then combine these into new rows. Creating a non-overlapping set of date ranges.

The bit that I need the most help with is the consolidations of the 'feature' column which will concatenate each feature into the format below.

```
ID  | START_DATE | END_DATE   | FEATURE
---------------------------------------
001 | 1995-08-01 | 1997-12-31 | 1
001 | 1998-01-01 | 2000-06-13 | 4
001 | 2000-06-14 | 2013-03-31 | 45
001 | 2013-04-01 | 2017-03-31 | 458
002 | 1929-10-01 | 2006-05-25 | 1
002 | 2006-05-26 | 2013-03-31 | 47
002 | 2013-04-01 | 2016-11-10 | 478
```

I've used the following to create the test data.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST (
    [ID] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [START_DATE] [date] NULL,
    [END_DATE] [date] NULL,
    [FEATURE] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


INSERT INTO #TEST

VALUES

('001','1998-01-01','2017-03-31',4),
('001','2000-06-14','2017-03-31',5),
('001','2013-04-01','2017-03-31',8),
('001','1995-08-01','1997-12-31',1),
('002','2006-05-26','2016-11-10',4),
('002','2006-05-26','2016-11-10',7),
('002','2013-04-01','2016-11-10',8),
('002','1929-10-01','2006-05-25',1)
```

Comment: What's your database?

Comment: Hi Guys, I'm using SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` :

```
select distinct t.id, t.START_DATE, t.END_DATE, coalesce(tt.feature, t.feature) as feature
from #test t outer apply
     ( select ' '+t1.feature
       from #test t1 
       where t1.id = t.id and t1.end_date = t.end_date and t1.start_date <= t.start_date
       order by t1.start_date
       for xml path('')
     ) tt(feature)
order by t.id, t.START_DATE;
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8501f0ab7b6b26416bac902de3d21cff).

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly to get the features.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that will set `DATE_END`. It looks like you are using `SQL Server`, but without or small modifications it will run almost on every db.

```
with grouped_data as
(
    select ID, START_DATE, END_DATE from #TEST group by ID, START_DATE, END_DATE
) 
,cte as
(
    select 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by start_date) as nr
    from grouped_data
)
select 
     c1.ID
    ,c1.START_DATE
    ,case when c1.nr <> 1 then isnull(DATEADD(DAY, -1, c2.START_DATE), c1.END_DATE) ELSE c1.END_DATE end as END_DATE  
from cte as c1
left join cte as c2
    on c1.ID = c2.ID
    and c1.nr = c2.nr -1
order by c1.ID
```

If you have `SQL Server 2017` you can easly transform `FEATURE` using `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: What if `('001','2013-04-01','2017-03-15',8)` ?

Comment: You know, you can easily break every select with another test data. It works for the provided data.